# Import all libraries from Python package in pantsbuild

Tags: python-3.x, build, package, pants

I want to import all the resources in my models/sources directory, into another target in pants build my contents of root/models/sources:

```
├── base.py
├── BUILD
├── design.py
├── email.py
├── __init__.py
└── project_management.py
```

The contents of my build file are as follows:

```
python_library(
    name="base",
    sources=["base.py"],
    dependencies=["root/models/tokens/__init__.py:__init__"]
)

python_library(
    name="design",
    sources=["design.py"],
    dependencies=[":base"]
)

python_library(
    name="email",
    sources=["email.py"],
    dependencies=[":base"]
)

python_library(
    name="project_management",
    sources=["project_management.py"],
    dependencies=[
        ":base",
        "root/models/tokens/__init__.py:__init__"
    ]
)

python_library(
    name="__init__",
    sources=["__init__.py"],
    dependencies=[
        ":base",
        ":design",
        ":email",
        ":project_management"
    ]
)
```

Now in another target, I have an

```
from root.models.sources import *
```

How would I set up the dependencies of this other target to import all the libraries in models/sources ?
p.s I know using * is not best, but that's the simplest form. Also, **init** is a Factory.

Comment: Thinking about this now... I can probably just import the __init__, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: (－‸ლ) that worked perfectly... okay hope this helped someone else in need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the **init** as long as it's a Factory that references all the other files in the package.
eg:

```
from root.models.sources.base import Source
from root.models.sources.design import DesignSource
from root.models.sources.email import EmailSource
from root.models.sources.project_management import \
    ProjectManagementSource


def SourceFactory(source: str = "default"):
    sources = {
        "default": Source,
        "foo1": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo2": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo3": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo4": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo5": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo6": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo7": ProjectManagementSource,
        "foo8": EmailSource,
        "foo9": DesignSource,
    }

    return sources[source] if source in sources.keys() else Source
```